# Mongo attempts to create a field on update though I don't need this

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I want to update a single field in all the embedded documents that match a query.

My update operation:

```
$set: { 'rows.baseValue': toValue }
```

However, I get an error of

> Cannot create field 'baseValue' in element {rows: [ { baseName:
>   "Belts", baseAttr: "Detail", baseValue: "Knot", action: "delete",
>   customName: "", customAttr: "", customValue: "", _id:
>   ObjectId('5c692860843d26064d1f142a') }

mind that i do have baseValue field in this document, why it's trying to create another `baseValue` field and how to make it just update the existing value of existing `baseValue` field?

Document to modify:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c692860843d26064d1f1429"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-02-17T09:24:49.253Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-02-17T09:24:49.253Z"),
    "translationName" : "deleteLex",
    "vertical" : "fashion",
    "defaultAction" : "delete",
    "rows" : [ 
        {
            "baseName" : "Belts",
            "baseAttr" : "Detail",
            "baseValue" : "Knot",
            "action" : "delete",
            "customName" : "",
            "customAttr" : "",
            "customValue" : "",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c692860843d26064d1f142a")
        }, 
        {
            "baseName" : "Belts",
            "baseAttr" : "Detail",
            "baseValue" : "Pockets",
            "action" : "delete",
            "customName" : "",
            "customAttr" : "",
            "customValue" : "",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c692860843d26064d1f142b")
        }, 
        {
            "baseName" : "Belts",
            "baseAttr" : "Detail",
            "baseValue" : "NewValue",
            "action" : "delete",
            "customName" : "",
            "customAttr" : "",
            "customValue" : "",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5c692860843d26064d1f142c")
        }]
}
```

Comment: Could you paste the document you're trying to modify ?

Comment: Yes, added to the question description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update all elements in an array you need the [postional all operator $[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/), try:

```
db.col.update({ "_id" : ObjectId("5c692860843d26064d1f1429") }, { $set: { "rows.$[].baseValue": toValue } })
```

Otherwise `$set` will try to create new value on existing array which is not possible

Comment: I tried a lot, it worked with $, updating the first element, but with $[] it does not work for me for some reason

Comment: Did you check your MongoDB version ? `$[]` was introduced in 3.6

Comment: "mongodb": "^2.2.16",

Comment: I mean server version but maybe also client needs to be upgraded

Comment: > db.version()
3.6.9
>